# Bluetooth settings

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Trying to dynamically setup a bluetooth conversation. Managed to track down an issue that I cannot figure out. Within peripheralManagerDidUpdateState; setting up service. Now this code works!

```
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    if (peripheral.state != .PoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    if (peripheral.state == .PoweredOn) {
        transferCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: cbtransfer, properties: .Notify, value: nil, permissions: .Readable)
        transferEvak = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: cbevak, properties: .Notify, value: nil, permissions: .Readable)
        transferPlay = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: characteristicsArray[3], properties: .Notify, value: nil, permissions: .Readable)
        transferService = CBMutableService(type: cbservice, primary: true)
        transferService.characteristics = [transferCharacteristic, transferEvak,transferPlay]
 peripheralManager!.addService(transferService)
        peripheralManager!.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey :[cbservice]])
```

Note characteristicArray is defined and populated with UUIDs I dynamically create.

```
var characteristicsArray = [CBUUID]()
```

Ok; but I don't really want to have to add characteristics one by one in my transferService.characteristics; I want to do something like this.

```
transferService.characteristics = CBMutableServicesCharacteristicsArray
```

But this doesn't work, it seems I have to define a transferService.characteristics as a static array of values? What have I missed here? Why?

Comment: I don't understand your question - Whether you create an array and assign it to `transferService.characteristics` in one line as you have or whether you create the array in another line and then assign it, it is the same thing.  You will have you create the 3 `CBMutableCharacteristics` the way you are regardless.

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing. Only the smarter way with the array doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the code that doesn't work?  I don't follow what you are saying.